# Algorithm to determine if number is between two numbers in modular arithmetic

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to write a function that answers the question: if you start counting at `a` and stop counting at `b`, is `c` in that range (aka is `c` between `a` and `b`).

Normally `a < c && c < b` would suffice, but I'm in modular arithmetic:

[image: (Diagram)]

Counter-clockwise is increasing.

Green colors: are values for c where the algorithm should indicate true (where c is between a and b)

Blue colors: are values for c where the algorithm should indicate false (where c is not between a and b) (which happens to be the same as where c is between **b and a**)

The simple `a < c && c < b` fails where the range of `a` and `b` crosses over 0.

For example, say A = 300 and B = 45. If C is 10 then the function should return true: **300**, 301, 302 ... 359, 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 8, 9, **10**, 11, 12 ... 43, 44, **45**. Therefore, 10 is between 300 and 45 in mod 360.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to determine is if one hue is between two other hues, where hues are specified in degrees around a color wheel (which is a mod 360 system). It would be great if the answer was in terms of mod n so it would solve the general case and not be specific to my problem though.

Comment: I think there are 3 cases: a≤x≤b OR b≤a≤x OR x≤b≤a (assuming the numbers are in canonical form 0≤a,b,x<n). Someone smarter might simplify using XOR.

Comment: Just subtract `a` from all three numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First calculate `a mod n`, `b mod n`, and `c mod n`.

If `a < b` then we need to check that `a < c && c < b`. This is the simple case where modular arithmetic doesn't play a huge role.

Because [a, b] and [b, a] form disjoint regions, instead of trying to deal with the problem of crossing 0, we can test the reverse for cases where `b < a`. If `b < c && c < a` is true, c is actually between b and a and therefore not between a and b.

Code sample:

```
a = a % n;  // % = mod
b = b % n;
c = c % n;

if (a < b) {
    if (a < c && c < b) return true;
    else return false;
} else { // b < a
    if (b < c && c < a) return false;   // if in [b, a] then not in [a, b]
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: One-liner (assuming _a_, _b_ and _c_ are already in _[0,n)_ ): `return (a < b) ? (a < c && c < b) : !(b < c && c < a);`

Answer (score 3):

```
bool between = C<A ^ C<B ^ B<A;
```

Answer (score 1):

The number will be between the given two numbers if **either** of following three conditions is satisfied.

**Condition 1**:

```
c mod n > a mod n && c mod n < b mod n
```

**Condition 2**:

```
a mod n > b mod n && c mod n < b mod n.
```

**Condition 3**:

```
a mod n > b mod n && c mod n > a mod n.
```

Comment: @KevinJohnson The first condition is straight forward.

Comment: @KevinJohnson The second and third condition handles the case of modulo arithmetic. Just take some examples and it will be clear.